# How to ProxyPass if the request doesn't correspond to a file

Tags: apache

I'm trying to implement the following behavior:
If the request corresponds to a file in `/var/www/html`, then serve it, else, ProxyPass to a different hostname and port.
I am aware of the `RewriteCond` directive and that we can exclude some path from a `ProxyPass` but that doesn't help me achieve what I want.

At the moment my config looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /backend/ http://server:8080/backend/
    ProxyPassReverse /backend/ http://server:8080/backend/
    ProxyPass / http://client:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://client:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /backend/ http://server:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /backend/ http://server:8080/backend/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule / http://client:4000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse / http://client:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have edited my answer to provide my current config. Can you tell me what it would look like after having implemented your solution? Do I have to embed the `Directory` section inside the `VirtualHost`?

Comment: Can you confirm that the `ProxyPassReverse` lines are taken only when the previous `RewriteCond` are true?

Comment: no, but if no proxying was done, then there is nothing to reverse

Comment: and if a proxying is done, which `ProxyPassReverse` is taken?

Comment: the first one that is matches pattern (that is why it is important that `/backend/` is above `/`)